# Node.js: Multer upload with promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I have this express route with multer file-upload. When the upload is complete, I would like to encode the image to base64 and send with response.

However when I do it like this, the code tries to execute the base64 encoding before the file is created to the folder.

**Edit**: Added storage & upload functions

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        if (!fs.existsSync('./uploads')) {
            fs.mkdirSync('./uploads');
        }
        let path = './uploads';
        callback(null, path);
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
        let fileExt = file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
        if (!imageFilter(fileExt)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    },
    onError: function (err, next) {
        console.log('error', err);
        next(err);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1000 * 1000 * 2 // 2 MB
    }
}).single('file');

router.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var directory = 'uploads';
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var file of files) {
            fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
    });
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'File is too large. (Max 2MB)'
            });
        }

        var file = req.file;
        var base64str = base64_encode('./uploads/' + file.originalname);

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            url: 'http://' + ip.address() + ':' + constants.PORT + '/api/uploads/' + file.originalname,
            image: 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64str
        });
    });
});
```

What would be the smartest way to achieve the right order of operations. Possibly promises or async/await?

Comment: Could you please add the `upload` function code ?

Comment: Oh right yeah, sorry.

Comment: What type of storage have you implemented?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This solution worked for me :

**Node v8.4.0 is required for this**

```
//app.js
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Uploader = require('./Uploader.js');
const uploader = new Uploader();

app.post('/upload', uploader.startUpload);


//Uploader.js

const util = require("util");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const multer = require('multer');

class Uploader {

    constructor() {
        const storageOptions = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, __dirname + '/uploads/')
            },
            filename: function(req, file, cb) {
                crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function(err, raw) {
                    cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname);
                });
            }
        });

        this.upload = multer({ storage: storageOptions });
    }

    async startUpload(req, res) {
        let filename;

        try {
            const upload = util.promisify(this.upload.any());

            await upload(req, res);

            filename = req.files[0].filename;
        } catch (e) {
            //Handle your exception here
        }

        return res.json({fileUploaded: filename});
    }
}
```

**Edit** :
The library "**util**" provide you a "**promisify**" method which will give you the possibility to avoid something called the "callback hell". It converts a callback-based function to a Promise-based one.

This is a small example to understand my code above:

```
const util = require('util');

function wait(seconds, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback();
  }, seconds);
}

function doSomething(callType) {
  console.log('I have done something with ' + callType + ' !');
}

// Default use case
wait(2 * 1000, () => {
  doSomething('callback');
});

const waitPromisified = util.promisify(wait);

// same with promises
waitPromisified(2000).then((response) => {
  doSomething('promise');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});

// same with async/await

(async () => {
  await waitPromisified(2 * 1000);
  doSomething('async/await');
})();
```

Will print :

```
I have done something with callback !
I have done something with promise !
I have done something with async/await !
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Promisify was all I needed.

Comment: @SrishtiGupta that's not very helpful. Can you update your question with how you used util.promisify?

Comment: I edit my answer with a small example @qodeninja if it's not clear for you.

Comment: This is gold! Thank you!

Comment: Had a problem when using the above as the `Uploader` instance was `null` inside the `startUpload` method. I needed to change the following:

`app.post('/upload', (req, res) =>{
  uploader.startUpload(req, res);
})`