# Uploading multiple files step-by-step and listing those already uploaded (NodeJS + Multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I'm using NodeJS + Multer for uploading multiple files in a single step. The selected files (using file-input) are shown in a list. This works fine. Now I would like to give a respond after each file, which has been uploaded successfully (eg. by adding a checkmark symbol).

Here is the current post request + multer storage object + upload function (nothing special):

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, '/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userfiles',50);

app.post('/api/upload',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log(req.files);
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error Uploading!");
        }
        res.end("Upload Successful!");
    });
});
```

As far as I understand, the upload function processes the whole storage object with all files inside of multer. I do not see any chance to place my success-response at all. My idea is to split the request and to iterate over each file inside the request, upload it as a single file and make the success-response. See my pseudo code:

```
app.post('/api/upload',function(req,res){

for (var SingleFile in req)
    upload(SingleFile,res,next) 
    res.write("uploaded "+SingleFile)
});
```

How would I do that?

Other approach: Using client side JQuery to somehow get the input-files and invoke post requests for every file.

What I would like to avoid is observing the destination folder for completly written files.

Thanks for any help, hint or comment.

Comment: In theory you could loop over an array of files and return a promise of a single upload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46193480/7888000. This might be the solution you looking for.

Comment: @parndepu Thank you for this link, but I'm afraid, that  `util.promisify(this.upload.any());` won't give me access to files, that are uploaded. Anyway, I didn't manage it with this example. Should I go with a different Node library for uploading??