# Express JS Multer async not working after refactoring

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, multer

I have been trying to refactor this code:
https://github.com/shubhambattoo/node-js-file-upload
into several modules.
I have largely succeeded, but I am having a problem with the upload returning to the home page before the upload has completed - async problem. The original does not have the problem, but i have tried many different approaches and am not getting anywhere. I feel the issue is where the upload middleware calls the next() function to redirect.

#### app.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const methodOverride = require('method-override');

// Middleware
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.json());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// DB connection then gridfs
require('./startup2/conn')(app);
require('./startup2/storage')(app);

// Application routes
require('./startup2/routes')(app);

// Server
const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server started on " + port);
});
```

#### conn.js

```js
module.exports = function(app) {

  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  
  // DB
  //const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/node-file-upl";
  const mongoURI = 'mongodb://dbuser:pass@0.0.0.0:27017/sro';
  
  // connection
  const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
  conn.collection('uploads');  // Set the name of the MongoDB collection
  app.locals.conn = conn;
  
  // const upload = require('./storage');
  // app.locals.upload = upload;
}
```

#### storage.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const multer = require("multer");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://dbuser:pass@0.0.0.0:27017/sro';
const crypto = require("crypto");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function(app) {

  // Storage
  const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'uploads' // The MongoDb collection name
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({ storage:storage, limits: { fileSize: 10000000} });
  app.locals.upload = upload;

  conn = app.locals.conn;
  //console.log("Conn is: ", conn);
  conn.once("open", () => {
    //console.log("init the gfs stream"); // init stream
    app.locals.gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
      bucketName: "uploads"
    });
  });
}
```

#### routes.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

const files = require('../routes/files');

console.log('Setting up routes in startup/routes.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
  
  const upload = app.locals.upload;
  console.log("Multer upload array", upload);

  app.use('/', files);
}
```

#### files.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const util = require('util');

//const config = require('config');

// @route GET / 
// @desc Loads form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  if(!gfs) {
    console.log('some error occurred, check connection to db');
    res.send('some error occurred, check connection to db');
    process.exit(0);
  }
  gfs.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.render('index', {
        files: false
      });
    } else {
      const f = files
        .map(file => {
          if (
            file.contentType === 'image/png' ||
            file.contentType === 'image/jpeg'
          ) {
            file.isImage = true;
          } else {
            file.isImage = false;
          }
          return file;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
          return (
            new Date(b['uploadDate']).getTime() -
            new Date(a['uploadDate']).getTime()
          );
        });

      return res.render('index', {
        files: f
      });
    }

    // return res.json(files);
  });
});

// TODO - async fix needed
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540560/node-js-multer-upload-with-promise 
// Currently file upload completes AFTER redirect to home page :-( 

// @route POST /upload
// @desc Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload',

  (req,res,next) => {

    console.log('@route POST /upload body',req.body);
    console.log('First /upload middleware - upload single file:', "upload");
    app.use('/upload',req.app.locals.upload.single('file'));
    next();
  }, 
  (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('Second /upload middleware - the redirect');
    //res.json({file : req.body});
    res.redirect('/');
    next();

  }
);

// @route GET /files
// @desc Display all files in JSON
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'no files exist'
      });
    }

    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc Display single file object
app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.find(
    {
      filename: req.params.filename
    },
    (err, file) => {
      if (!file) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'no file exists'
        });
      }

      return res.json(file);
    }
  );
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc Display Image
app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
  // console.log('id', req.params.id)
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  const file = gfs
    .find({
      filename: req.params.filename
    })
    .toArray((err, files) => {
      if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'no files exist'
        });
      }
      gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(req.params.filename).pipe(res);
    });
});

// @route DELETE /files/del/:id
// @desc Delete chunks from the db
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.delete(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id), (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(404).json({ err: err.message });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

#### index.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Mongo File Uploads</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center display-4 my-4">Mongo File Uploads</h1>
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="custom-file mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
            <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <% if(files){ %>
          <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
            <div class="card card-body mb-3">
              <% if(file.isImage) { %>
                <img src="image/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                <% } else { %>
                  <%= file.filename %>
                    <% } %>
                      <form method="POST" action="/files/<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                      </form>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
              <% } else { %>
                <p>No files to show</p>
                <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can I get Github link for your refactored code, so that I can help you.

Comment: https://github.com/stevegroom/redogridfsstorage

Comment: I fixed it - thanks' for trying anyway.

Comment: @NithinKJoy - the bounty is there if you can add any value ...

Comment: you are welcome. I am now working on your code to make it better. The answer will be uploaded shortly.

Comment: thank you for the bounty... Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I modified the saved upload reference in db.js to refer to the single() function and then called the upload function with callback (I think).

in db.js :

```js
 const upload = multer({ storage:storage, limits: { fileSize: 10000000} }).single('file');
  app.locals.upload = upload;
```

and in files.js

```js
    const upload = req.app.locals.upload;

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err); // An error occurred when uploading 
        return
      }
      // Everything went fine 
      next();
    })
```

**db.js:**

```js
module.exports = function(app) {

  const crypto = require("crypto");
  const path = require("path");
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");
  const multer = require("multer");
  const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
 
  // DB
  const mongoURI = 'mongodb://dbuser:pass@0.0.0.0:27017/sro';

  // Connection
  const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });
  app.locals.conn = conn;
  
  // init GFS
  let gfs;
  conn.once("open", () => {
    //console.log("init the gfs stream"); // init stream
    gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
      bucketName: "uploads"
    });
    app.locals.gfs = gfs;
  });

  // Storage
  const storage = new GridFsStorage({ 
    db: conn,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'uploads' // The MongoDb collection name
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }  
  });
  app.locals.storage = storage;
    
  const upload = multer({ storage:storage, limits: { fileSize: 10000000} }).single('file');
  app.locals.upload = upload;

}
```

**files.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const util = require('util');

//const config = require('config');

// @route GET / 
// @desc Loads form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  if(!gfs) {
    console.log('some error occurred, check connection to db');
    res.send('some error occurred, check connection to db');
    process.exit(0);
  }
  gfs.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.render('index', {
        files: false
      });
    } else {
      const f = files
        .map(file => {
          if (
            file.contentType === 'image/png' ||
            file.contentType === 'image/jpeg'
          ) {
            file.isImage = true;
          } else {
            file.isImage = false;
          }
          return file;
        })
        .sort((a, b) => {
          return (
            new Date(b['uploadDate']).getTime() -
            new Date(a['uploadDate']).getTime()
          );
        });

      return res.render('index', {
        files: f
      });
    }

    // return res.json(files);
  });
});

// TODO - async fix needed
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540560/node-js-multer-upload-with-promise 
// Currently file upload completes AFTER redirect to home page :-( 

// @route POST /upload
// @desc Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload',

  (req,res,next) => {

    console.log('@route POST /upload body',req.body);
    console.log('First /upload middleware - upload single file:', "upload");

    const upload = req.app.locals.upload;

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err); // An error occurred when uploading 
        return
      }
      // Everything went fine 
      next();
    })
  }, 
  (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('Second /upload middleware - the redirect');
    res.redirect('/');
    next();

  }
);

// @route GET /files
// @desc Display all files in JSON
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'no files exist'
      });
    }

    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc Display single file object
app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.find(
    {
      filename: req.params.filename
    },
    (err, file) => {
      if (!file) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'no file exists'
        });
      }

      return res.json(file);
    }
  );
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc Display Image
app.get('/image/:filename', (req, res) => {
  // console.log('id', req.params.id)
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  const file = gfs
    .find({
      filename: req.params.filename
    })
    .toArray((err, files) => {
      if (!files || files.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'no files exist'
        });
      }
      gfs.openDownloadStreamByName(req.params.filename).pipe(res);
    });
});

// @route DELETE /files/del/:id
// @desc Delete chunks from the db
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs = req.app.locals.gfs;
  gfs.delete(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id), (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(404).json({ err: err.message });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

All the code is here: https://github.com/stevegroom/redogridfsstorage

Steve

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/upload',

  (req,res,next) => req.app.locals.upload.single('file')(req,res,next), 
  (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('Second /upload middleware - the redirect');
    //res.json({file : req.body});
    res.redirect('/');
    next();

  }
);
```

Have you try this ?

And i think the last next wouldn't work because you have called res function

```
res.redirect('/');
next();
```

Comment: Hi, I successfully tested your optimised version and learnt from it, however I think i'll keep the longer version I created as that will be easier to understand if i need to come back to it.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats you did it. Here I would like to suggest something to you.

You have used crypto module to just generate the name for the file. That's nice and you could use its full capability by encrypting the images/files. Here is the code.

Encrption

```
//I use aes-256-ctr encryption
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let pass = "vhg%^yg*i993DE$%G3d$f^g&|][jup(]"//Password should be 32 chars long
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', pass, iv)
//crypted is the encrypted data
let crypted = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(Your image/file), cipher.final()]);
```

Decryption

```
iv = your image/file.buffer.slice(0, 16);
chunk = your imge/file.buffer.slice(16);
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', "vhg%^yg*i993DE$%G3d$f^g&|][jup(]", iv)
//decrypted data(dec)
var dec = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(chunk), decipher.final()]);
let buffer = new Buffer.from(dec)
```

And in your GitHub code, you just defined `port=3000` But the better implementation will be `let port=process.env.port||3000` In deployment, you have to do so. Otherwise, it will throw some error (you probably know this)