# What is best practice for informing user (client side app) that the server side app is processing their uploaded file. React, Node & MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I have a backend service build in node.js interfacing with mongodb and a client side service using react and next js.

The logged in user is able to upload a file but doesn't currently get any feedback that the server side application is processing their file.

I want to inform the user that:

1. the file is being processed
2. the status of the this (not vital)
3. if it was done successfully or there were errors (this is the most important)

I'm using multer to handle the file upload, I then store the file and call a function on the server using fast-csv to read the file stream, clean the data and upload it to mongodb.

I would like to know what the best practice is for communicating with the client side. I tried using the progressEvent but this seems to be only for the initial upload of the file.

I think I need to ask the server what the status is but I'm not sure how this would look. Would I set a timer on the client side that asks the server at intervals the status of the import process?

Or should I look into websockets to solve the problem?

Comment: Does this help you, Joel? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540560/node-js-multer-upload-with-promise

Comment: BTW, I use Redux with React and it makes it extremely simple to do this type of functionality. You can have a REQUEST, SUCCESS &  ERROR constant and then adjust state accordingly after dispatching a specific action, such as file upload. In REQUEST you can set a "processing: true" state and then "processing: false" state upon success. I use it all the time for showing a spinning loader while receiving data from the database.

Comment: You can Use sockets to show progress and other things with image upload it is very good practice to use Sockets to show real time errors and upload progress